# How to ignore duplicate status rows in events table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

My source events table looks like this:

[image: Source Table]

The result set I need should not include the duplicated "OPEN" values (4, 5), and if possible, return the first occurrence only.

The closest I've been able to get is to group them by looking at answers discussing "gaps and islands" but I'm lost as to how to actually "eliminate" the unneeded rows.

https://dbfiddle.uk/4eIDDmXx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using gaps and islands, I'd suggest using a simple `LAG` to get the previous row's `OpenOrClosed` value - then check if that previous row's `OpenOrClosed` value is different from the current row's.

This involves a first SELECT to get all rows, with LAG to get the corresponding previous row's value - and then a second SELECT to filter out only those that are different.

See this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/posiTP2_) which was based on your original one.

```
SELECT [ID]
       ,[EventDateTime]
       ,[SourceEventID]
       ,[OpenOrClosed] 
FROM
    (SELECT [ID]
           ,[EventDateTime]
           ,[SourceEventID]
           ,[OpenOrClosed]
           ,LAG([OpenOrClosed], 1) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS [LastOOC]
    FROM    [dbo].[test]
    ) AS SourceData
WHERE LastOOC IS NULL OR OpenOrClosed <> LastOOC
```

Results are as below

```
ID  EventDateTime             SourceEventID OpenOrClosed
1   2013-01-31 14:20:00.000   331832        OPEN
2   2013-04-18 14:44:00.000   338907        CLOSED
3   2013-04-19 15:30:00.000   341210        OPEN
6   2013-04-24 12:22:00.000   339250        CLOSED
7   2013-05-08 12:32:00.000   340281        OPEN
8   2013-05-08 12:33:00.000   340282        CLOSED
9   2013-05-08 12:34:00.000   340255        OPEN
```